# Troubleshooting MutableState Updates in Jetpack Compose App with StateFlow and Combine

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, kotlin-coroutines, kotlin-flow, kotlin-stateflow

I'm developing an app that uses Jetpack Compose. In my project, I'm using StateFlow combined with Combine because I need my screen to be fully loaded only after all the services have completed.

So far, everything is working as expected. However, I'm currently facing a challenge when trying to refresh the screen. When I attempt to modify the data by changing the MutableState, I notice that the same data continues to be displayed without any updates.

Could you please guide me on how to proceed in this situation?

Here's the relevant code snippet:

```kotlin
private val _uiState = MutableStateFlow(HomeUiState())

val uiState: StateFlow<HomeUiState> =
    combine(
        retrieveLanguageCollectionsUseCase(),
        retrievePhrasesPendingReviewUseCase(),
        retrieveConsecutiveDaysUseCase(),
        retrieveGoalsUseCase(),
        _uiState,
        userDomain
    ) { languageCollectionsStatus,
        phrasesPendingReviewStatus,
        consecutiveDaysStatus,
        goals,
        uiState, userDomain,
        ->
        if (languageCollectionsStatus.isLoadingStatus.not() &&
            phrasesPendingReviewStatus.isLoadingStatus.not() &&
            consecutiveDaysStatus.isLoadingStatus.not() &&
            userDomain != null
        ) {
            uiState.copy(
                userDomain = userDomain,
                goals = goals,
                isPieChartGoalsVisible = true,
                phrasesPendingReviewStatus = phrasesPendingReviewStatus,
                languageCollectionsStatus = languageCollectionsStatus,
                consecutiveDaysStatus = consecutiveDaysStatus,
            )
        } else {
            uiState
        }
    }.stateIn(
        scope = viewModelScope,
        started = WhileSubscribed(5_000),
        initialValue = _uiState.value
    )
```